# How to setup Subdomains for Geoserver WMS with Apache and Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, tiles, geoserver, subdomain

We are running a bunch of WMS with a GeoServer. The GeoServer is running inside a tomcat webserver and the tomcat is behind an apache webserver.

At the moment we can reach our WMS like this: `http://domain.com/geoserver/layer/wms?....`

What we need are different subdomains for the WMS, that all point to the same GeoServer intance, e.g.:

`http://t1.domain.com/geoserver/layer/wms?....`
`http://t2.domain.com/geoserver/layer/wms?....`
`http://t3.domain.com/geoserver/layer/wms?....`

Any ideas how we can achieve/configure this with the configuration mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do that with Apache/Tomcat. The domain/subdomain names are the way other hosts reach yours, and *after* they find it is when Apache and Tomcat come into play.

You should ask your network admin of Internet provider for that or maybe think of another approach like `http://domain.com/t1/geoserver/layer/wms?... http://domain.com/t2/geoserver/layer/wms?`, etc.

I suggest you [**Varnish reverse proxy**](https://www.varnish-cache.org/) as it is a light-weight software with an easy configuration language.